# Mingw GCC Linker complains when using std option flag

Tags: c, linker, mingw, ld

I'm using Mingw's gcc compiler but when I started using the -std options, the linker started complaining about references (except for -std=gnuXX).

I can't find anything about this (maybe I'm really bad at research) because most of the results are on linux and/or relate to other problems with ld..

Here is the command I typed :
`gcc src/main.c -o bin/main.exe -std=c11` The same occurs with c89,c99,c17 etc..

Here is my test code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    printf("Cool\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is the command output

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(mbrscan.o):(.text+0xb6): 
undefined reference to `SetLastError@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(wcharmap.o):(.text+0x208): undefined reference to `WideCharToMultiByte@32'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingwex.a(codeset.o):(.text+0xbe): 
undefined reference to `GetCPInfo@8'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingwex.a(codeset.o):(.text+0x143): undefined reference to `GetCPInfo@8'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/libgcc_eh.a(emutls.o): in function `_gthread_mutex_init_function':
/home/keith/builds/mingw/gcc-9.2.0-mingw32-cross-native/mingw32/libgcc/./gthr-default.h:639: undefined reference to `CreateSemaphoreW@16'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/libgcc_eh.a(emutls.o): in function `_gthread_key_create':
/home/keith/builds/mingw/gcc-9.2.0-mingw32-cross-native/mingw32/libgcc/./gthr-default.h:590: undefined reference to `TlsAlloc@0'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: /home/keith/builds/mingw/gcc-9.2.0-mingw32-cross-native/mingw32/libgcc/./gthr-default.h:597: undefined reference to `__mingwthr_key_dtor'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/libgcc_eh.a(emutls.o): in function `_gthread_getspecific':
/home/keith/builds/mingw/gcc-9.2.0-mingw32-cross-native/mingw32/libgcc/./gthr-default.h:621: undefined reference to `SetLastError@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/libgcc_eh.a(emutls.o): in function `_gthread_mutex_lock':
/home/keith/builds/mingw/gcc-9.2.0-mingw32-cross-native/mingw32/libgcc/./gthr-default.h:655: undefined reference to `InterlockedIncrement@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/libgcc_eh.a(emutls.o): in function `_gthread_mutex_unlock':
/home/keith/builds/mingw/gcc-9.2.0-mingw32-cross-native/mingw32/libgcc/./gthr-default.h:689: undefined reference to `InterlockedDecrement@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: /home/keith/builds/mingw/gcc-9.2.0-mingw32-cross-native/mingw32/libgcc/./gthr-default.h:690: undefined reference to `ReleaseSemaphore@12'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/libgcc_eh.a(emutls.o): in function `_gthread_setspecific':
/home/keith/builds/mingw/gcc-9.2.0-mingw32-cross-native/mingw32/libgcc/./gthr-default.h:629: undefined reference to `TlsSetValue@8'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/libgcc_eh.a(emutls.o): in function `_gthread_once':
/home/keith/builds/mingw/gcc-9.2.0-mingw32-cross-native/mingw32/libgcc/./gthr-default.h:562: undefined reference to `InterlockedIncrement@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/libgcc_eh.a(emutls.o): in function `_gthread_mutex_lock':
/home/keith/builds/mingw/gcc-9.2.0-mingw32-cross-native/mingw32/libgcc/./gthr-default.h:656: undefined reference to `WaitForSingleObject@8'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: /home/keith/builds/mingw/gcc-9.2.0-mingw32-cross-native/mingw32/libgcc/./gthr-default.h:662: undefined reference to `InterlockedDecrement@4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm also wondering if I should use Mingw-w64 or Clang/LLVM instead.. ?

**EDIT : It works fine with Mingw-w64 so I switched, thanks !**

Comment: Try using `-lwin32` switch (at the end of your current line)

Comment: It would definitely be better to use mingw-w64 instead of mingw.org . You will save a lot of time not bashing your head against issues like this

Comment: Tried it :
`C:\Users\fruxode\#projects\cfrux>gcc src/main.c -o bin/main.exe -std=c11 -lwin32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwin32
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Well, I guess I'll try it out with Mingw64.. what about Clang/LLVM ?

Comment: When you add things like `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors`, they strip out all non-standard functions from the standard headers, which could explain some errors. In this specific case, it rather seems like a library/path installation hiccup though.

Comment: As for Mingw, I only think Mingw64 is maintained. The older one just called Mingw without 64, isn't maintained since 10 years back or so.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah makes sense, I now use msys2 with mingw64 and except some dll hell with deploying gtk apps, I didn't have any issue.